# How to crop images in Google Docs permanently?

Tags: google-docs, images

I write technical blogs for which I frequently need to take screenshots of my screen. It's easier to paste directly into my Google document and crop it there rather than opening an application to crop the image and upload to my docs.

When I crop images in Docs, it looks all good but when I paste the article into the editor in my site, the image that I had cropped earlier appears the whole as if it was never cropped.

Could anybody suggest me the proper way of preserving the images cropped in Google Docs when migrated to another editor?

Comment: Image crop in Google Docs works like adding "mask" to original image, so there is no new "cropped" image produced.

Comment: @Kos So there's no solution to my problem?

Comment: Maybe you can switch to another online editor

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about doing this:

1. Save the image to keep. Found on the right sidebar and in the context menu, keep will let you access your cropped images across all Google products.
2. Use drawings. Instead of just pasting the screenshot directly into Google Docs, create a new drawing first in the doc and then paste it in the drawing. Crop it in the drawing. You can then export the drawing to png, and that drawing will show up in the docs as well.

Sadly the way that Google docs works won't let you permanently save a cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. > I frequently need to take screenshots of my screen. It's easier to paste directly into my Google document and crop it there rather than...

Please do keep this step exactly as it is. (take the screenshot of your screen, place it within the Google Doc, crop it, turn it, twist it, in other words change it to your liking)

2. Now take a screenshot of the image IN your Doc.
3. delete the previous image.
4. Replace it with the new "cropped"/altered one.
5. Resize/place it it in the document to the dimensions/place of your last image.
6. Save your document.
7. Enjoy :)

Comment: Have you tried any of the given solutions? Did any work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Goto:  File > Info > Inspect Document

You can then identify and automatically clean up a whole host of issues you may not want the end user to see, such as comments or...... cropped pictures.